# How to configure apt-cacher for ftp

Tags: debian, ftp, apt, apt-cache

A few days ago i set up an apt-cache server. The clients are configured to use it as a proxy. This is necessary because we usually use ftp (and i also feals "cleaner"). So my apt.conf looks like this:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://my.cache:3142"; # Still needed for the security repositories
Acquire::ftp::Proxy "ftp://my.cache:3142"; # I also tried "http://my.cache:3142";
```

The http requests work fine (I tested this by disabling the ftp proxy) but the ftp requests are hanging with the message [Logging in] and then fail with the message "Protocol corruption".

Does anyone know what to do? I would really like to continue using ftp.

The server is running apt-cacher.

Comment: What sort of proxy are you using on my.cache? Is it an ftp proxy server? Have you set up the required `ftp::ProxyLogin` script in the config to tell the proxy server what to connect to (as per the apt.conf documentation)?

Comment: I'm using apt-cacher. I didn't configured any needed authentication. Do i need to set it anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is simple, apt-cacher doesn't support FTP connections, only HTTP. It was meant to be a HTTP proxy, hence it doesn't support/serve FTP connections.

Comment: But the man page states it does. (section CLIENT CONFIGURATION->Access cache like a proxy)

Comment: @IchUndNichtDu like an HTTP proxy, not an FTP proxy. It may allow you to GET packages from FTP, but it won't offer them.

Comment: Are there alternatives which support ftp?

Comment: Maybe apt-ftparchive, but I do not make promisses.